# C++ variable on stack does not appear to be freed at end of function scope

Tags: c++, scope

I made the following short code to experiment and try to get a "first-hand" experience with when objects have their constructors and destructors called:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int bar)
    {
        this->bar = bar;
        std::cout << "Standard constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Standard destructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(const Foo &foo)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor called" << std::endl;
        this->bar = foo.bar;
    }
    inline int get_bar() { return bar; }
private:
    int bar;
};

Foo make_foo(int bar)
{
    Foo f1(bar);
    std::cout << "About to return foo with address of: " << &f1 << std::endl;
    return f1;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f2 = make_foo(3);
    std::cout << "New variable has address of: " << &f2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "And a value of " << f2.get_bar() << std::endl;
}
```

But something that I find strange occurs when I run this code. Like expected, "standard constructor called" is printed and the address of foo in that function is printed. But when the function ends, no destructor is called, and f2 actually has the same memory address as f1, even though, from my understanding, f1 should have gone out of scope and had its memory freed because it was on the stack, right? Or is this not the expected outcome in this situation?

My expectation is that the copy constructor would be called for f1 to be copied to f2, and then f1 would have its destructor called and f2 would occupy a different memory address.

In case anyone is curious, this is the actual output:

```
Standard constructor called                                                                          
About to return new foo with address of: 0x7fff518e5a88                                              
New variable has address of: 0x7fff518e5a88                                                          
And a value of 3                                                                                     
Standard destructor called
```

Interestingly, when I change the return type of `make_foo` to a reference type, the function executes almost as I expect it to, with f1 being destructed and f2 copying junk data.

Is this some specific case where a variable on the stack will not have its memory freed when it's being returned to be assigned to another variable that I should be aware of?

Comment: This is an instance of return value optimization (RVO).  `f1` is constructed right in the location that is the return value, since that's all it's really used for.

Comment: There is copy elision, which is permitted in all C++ standards, and (C++11 and later) specifically required in a number of circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is performing a return value optimization (RVO). You can read about it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization

Comment: Is this behavior guaranteed in C++11 onwards?

Comment: @AnonymousPerson More precisely, this is so called _named return value optmization_, which is never guaranteed, it's only optional even in C++17.